# Laravel Sum column of relationship table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 2 tables, 'Invoice table', and related 'linesInvoice' table.

To simplify it, I will say that the invoice lines table has only the invoice_id field for the relationship and total for the price.

Now, I need to get last invoices, with his totals (totals, is the sum of column 'total' in every line).
I've tried many examples, but none works for me correctly.

Controller:

```
$lastInvoices = Invoice::latest()
                          ->limit(10)
                          ->with(['invoiceLines'])->get();
```

Model for relation

```
public function invoiceLines()
{
    return $this->hasMany(InvoiceLines::class, 'invoice_id');
}
```

The result that I want for example looks like:

```
[
  Invoice_id => 1
  total => 500 //Sum of totals in lines of invoice 1
],
[
  Invoice_id => 2
  total => 300 //Sum of totals in lines of invoice 2
],
```

I guess I could go through all the invoices and lines in foreachs and make the sum. But I hope it can be done in the same query

Comment: another way of doing it without query is $invoice->invoiceLines->sum('your_column');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [withSum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) method. This method accept the relation method as first argument and column to sum as second argument

```
$lastInvoices = Invoice::latest()
                          ->limit(10)
                          ->withSum('invoiceLines','your_column_name')
                          ->with(['invoiceLines'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8^

```
Invoice::with('invoiceLines')->latest()->first()->invoiceLines()->sum('totle');
```

totle colme table invoiceLines

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).